# Get friend lists

Tags: performance, ecmascript-6, vkscript

I've never written on [VKScript](http://vk.com/dev/execute) (and on Javascript). I need high performance code to get more friend lists faster.

```
var targets = Args.t; // get params (ids)
// prepare all variables before loop
var all_friends = {};
var req;
var parametr = "";
var start = 0;
var q = {};
var user_friends = {};

// get each target from all targets
while(start <= targets.length)
{
    if (targets.substr(start, 1) != "," && start != targets.length)
    {
        parametr = parametr + targets.substr(start, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        // make request for each id
        q = {"user_id":parametr};
        req = API.friends.get(q);
        if (req) // if user is alive
        {
            user_friends = {"u":q["user_id"], "f":req["items"]};
        }
        else // if user is deleted, there is no friends
        {
            user_friends = {"u":q["user_id"], "f":[0]};
        }
        all_friends = all_friends + [user_friends];
        parametr = "";
    }
    start = start + 1;
}
return all_friends;
```

All suggestions and recommendations are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see only a minor improvement opportunity here.

In the following snippet, much of the code in the `if` and `else` branches is duplicated:

> ```
> if (req) // if user is alive
> {
>     user_friends = {"u":q["user_id"], "f":req["items"]};
> }
> else // if user is deleted, there is no friends
> {
>     user_friends = {"u":q["user_id"], "f":[0]};
> }
> ```

It would be better to refactor in a way that avoids duplication:

```
var friends = req ? req["items"] : [0];
user_friends = {"u":q["user_id"], "f": friends};
```

*(For what it's worth, I had more suggestions while I believed `vkscript` has `charAt` method like JavaScript, apparently it doesn't. See the edit history if ever interested.)*